# Why is Superman still not aware of the Phantom Zone projector being stolen?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lego-batman-movie

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, the Phantom Zone projector is the device made by Superman. It was stolen by Batman when Superman is busy in *Justice League Anniversary*.

Batman used the Phantom Zone projector on the Joker to send him to the Phantom Zone.

Whole the movie ended, Superman was still not aware that his own device got stolen - how is this possible?

Comment: Because... *"He's Batman"*